# does compiler call implicit destructor on an object initialised by new

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a doubt, as C++ (GNU g++) compiler call implicit d-tor with objects in stack. when it calls d-tor for an object, where memory - allocated with new.

```
struct abc{
   int a;
};

int main(){
 {
     abc ob1;
 }//! Here implicit ~abc() will be called

 {
 abc *ob2 = new abc();
 } //! Will comipler call d-tor for ob2 ?

 return 0;
}
```

Please help me to know, if compiler is not release memory of *ob2 then why it is doing like so?

Comment: You could easily answer your own question by adding `~abc() { std::cout << "destroying an instance of abc\n"; }`.

Comment: Demo: https://ideone.com/LpQloF

Answer (score 5):

No. You need to call `delete` on the object.

If you create an object dynamically in C++ (a non-managed language), you must call `delete` on the object to free up the memory on the heap.

Calling `delete` on the pointer to the object will call the destructor of the object you're deleting.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using a smart-pointer and you are not using an explicit `delete`, so the `ob2` object is going to leak.

If, however you use a smart-pointer it will get cleaned up when it leaves scope:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<abc> ob2( new abc() );
}
```

[unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will call `delete` on the 'owned' object automatically when `ob2` leaves scope.

Of course you should really use `make_unique` instead of calling `new` explicitly and that's a good place to use C++11 `auto` as well:

```
{
    auto ob2 = make_unique<abc>();
}
```

See [Smart Pointers (Modern C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp)

> In general in Modern C++, you shouldn't be calling `delete` explicitly in most cases. See the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) and in particular:
>
> C.149: *Use unique_ptr or shared_ptr to avoid forgetting to delete objects created using new*
>
> R.11: *Avoid calling new and delete explicitly*
>
> ES.60: *Avoid new and delete outside resource management functions*

Comment: I am thankful to everyone for all the reply.

Completely agreed that unique_ptr and make_unique specifies the ownership of the object and takes responsibility to release allocated memory when goes out of scope.

I would be interested to know, why C++ d-tor doesn't calls for memory allocated by new, as stack the pointer object goes out of scope at some point (including derived-base class hierarchy).

Comment: @Saket The compiler cannot possibly guess when memory should be deallocated because state changes at runtime, the automated alternative is garbage collection which incurs a runtime cost.

Comment: It goes back the origins of C and the philosophy of C++ built on that. C had a notion of "automatic variables" that are allocated on the stack, and 'heap' variables that are created with ``malloc`` and cleaned up manually with ``free``. ``new`` extends ``malloc`` with a call to the ctor; ``delete`` extends ``free`` with a call to the dtor. The whole point of a smart-pointer is to provide 'automatic variable' semantics for heap-allocated objects. In general, controlling proper 'ownership' of resources is the key challenge of "native" coding, and the reason why you can get better performance.

Comment: @George and Chuck Walbourn, I am thankful for the detailed replies.
Agreed as you said if we are allocating a pointer instance without safe guard (as smart-pointers or containers) then it would be programmer's responsibility to at-least have a garbage collector if he is ignoring delete in d-tor.